# Как включить HTTPS к подстановочному DNS

Tags: apache, ssl, https, cloudflare

### Не работает SSL сертификат на подстановочном субдомене

Имеется подстановочная DNS запись на `Cloudflare`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но при переходе по ней не работает ssl сертификат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройка `Apache`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName domain.ru
  ServerAlias domain.ru *.p.domain.ru
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:*порт*/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:*порт*/  

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /*путь до сертификата*
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /*путь до сертификата*
</VirtualHost>
```

Для остальных доменных записей все сертификаты работают корректно. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Давайте начнём с глупого вопроса - вы не забыли прописать https в адресе?

Comment: @andreymal нет, не забыл

Comment: Что интересного браузер пишет в кнопочке "Дополнительные"?

Comment: @andreymal обновил скриншот

Comment: Жаль, ничего конкретного. Пока остаётся только предположить, что используемый вами сертификат не подходит для этого домена

Comment: @andreymal у меня этот сертификат собственно и работает на этом домене, и на всех прочих поддоменах, не работает только на подстановочном субдомене

Comment: Потому что он, видимо, не подходит для подстановочного субдомена